# Custom template redirect based on url vars

Tags: template-redirect

I am using a custom URL on my menu to show the most viewed posts by passing the variables to the url as

http://website.com/?v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc

However I want to use a custom template to display the results.

I tried the following but it doest work. I am having trouble finding a fix, can anyone help.

```
function custom_template($template) {
  global $wp;
  if ($wp->query_vars['template']=='basic') {
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/basic.php';
  }
  else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter('template_redirect', 'custom_template');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to `exit` afterwards.

```
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'wpse85164_query_var_template' );
function wpse85164_query_var_template( $template )
{
    if ( 'basic' === get_query_var( 'template' ) )
        exit( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/basic.php' );

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Still not working :(( I cant seem to figure out whats wrong.